# Passenger rights during a flight

Tags: safety, aircraft, passenger-rights

Recently I faced an extraordinary situation during my flight inside the EU. A very large group of passengers (80% of all passengers, mostly men, probably football fans) already quite drunk during boarding, was behaving against safety instructions. They occupied the lavatory before and during take-off, creating a constant huge line to the WC, which prevented the crew from explaining the safety instructions normally, delivering the snacks and beverages (the corridor was occupied during the whole flight - 1.5 hours), and was generally behaving far beyond any regulations.

Some of them were also smoking, shouting and bothering other passengers. The cabin crew was obviously not able to deal with the situation (they didn't really try) and started selling alcohol to already very drunk passengers, which of course, escalated the whole situation.

I never had such a creepy flight and don't really know what a passenger can do in such situation. Is there any law that protects the passengers in such cases?  I just want to know, if there is any chance to get a compensation for this flight, and/or at least to prevent such cases in future

Thanks a million for your replies.

Comment: What kind of protection do you ask about or would you expect?

Comment: Well obviously neither me, nor other few passengers (not belonging to the drunk group) were feeling safe during this flight. As far as I know smoking and drinking too much is not allowed on board. Moreover, drunk passengers should not even be allowed to come on board. And as I said, the drunk passengers were not following the instructions of the cabin crew during take-off and landing, which affected other passengers. I just want to know, if there is any chance to get a compensation for this flight, and/or at least to prevent such cases in future. Thanks

Comment: I added you clarification to the question body.

Comment: Nope, no automatic right to compensation here - you can complain to the airline about the conduct of fellow passengers and its crew, and ask for compensation but they aren't obligated to provide you with any.  You could complain to the aviation authority in the origin, destination or airlines home country about the issues with smoking (banned on all EU flights by individual aviation authorities), drunkenness and issues with the mandated safety briefing, but again no automatic right to compensation exists there either.

Comment: Recently BBC television showed this kind of behavior, that airports and airlines do not follow their own code of conduct. It was said that some of MP's are working on it. Maybe you can find them as well. (That is, when you did fly from or to the UK.) I do not remember the details but I think it was in September 2017, August earliest.

Comment: The ultimate auhtority in that case is the Pilot In Command. PIC can refuse to takeoff with that wild hooligans but the lack of effort from the crew hints it's not a unseen case and possible the company can be less than pleased with a canceled flight (also guess what can happen you try to tell to that turb the fly is being cancelled, how do you can expect to remove all that guys from the plane without a fight?). That said it's must be some kind of team fan club, take not and try to avoid those guys (schedulled games from team X in town Y)

Comment: "How can you expect to remove all those guys from the plane without a fight"? If the pilot thinks the guys are dangerous, the airport will have unlimited amount of force available to remove them, and whether they try to fight will be quite irrelevant.

Comment: File a formal complaint. It is disgusting having to smell tobacco and witness such uncivility.

Comment: Smoking onboard a flight is illegal and definitely should be reported, if that is in deed what was going on. I am surprised none of the smoke alarms and detectors were triggered as this would have raised an alarm in the cockpit. Was this a private charter?

Comment: @gnasher729 Unlimited?  I expect it would have to be proportionate.

Comment: @gerrit i interpret unlimited as they may have more than 200 police available to remove unruly passenger. Not that they have 200 bullets to shoot each of them.

Comment: i definitely saw quite a lot of smoke, but as it did not smell that much, I guess that were e-cigaretts. Still as far as I know they are prohibited on board. anyway, this is definitely not an option to avoid flights during soccer weekends or so - I had no idea that there was some event where they were flying to. Interestingly - this was indeed a flight from UK, looks like it's some internal problem, if even BBC reported it... Do you guys know which authority I should complain to? The airline replied with a standard answer saying, they are sorry and hope to see me soon :)))

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Elevating my comment to an answer, as it's more appropriate as one.

Nope, no automatic right to compensation here - you can complain to the airline about the conduct of fellow passengers and its crew, and ask for compensation but they aren't obligated to provide you with any.

You could complain to the aviation authority in the origin, destination or airlines home country about the issues with smoking (banned on all EU flights by individual aviation authorities), drunkenness and issues with the mandated safety briefing, but again no automatic right to compensation exists there either.

Comment: I know @Stuart has complained to an authority about a lack of safety briefing on a flight before, and action was taken.  Might be a good idea.

Comment: Seems like this would be grounds for suspension of the crew for negligence, and possibly even the airline, so I'd definitely complain to the aviation authority above the airline.